# Where is Aria T'Loak in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

My quick question is, where is she Aria T'loak? If I'm not mistaken, she's suppose to be in the club at the number 3 location (on the map), but I don't see her.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: map of purgatory]

She's listed at the number 2 location, and will always be there.  She's sitting on the corner couch.

Answer (score 2):

After entering the club, go up the first set of stairs and take a right, she will be sitting on the red couch.

Answer (score 0):

In the Purgatory at the VIP lounge